# Checking if data exists in a mongodb collection in goLang?

Tags: mongodb, go

If i want to check if there currently exists at least one document in a collection, how would I go about doing this in GoLang?

Comment: Do a find. Mongo will return `mongo.ErrNoDocuments` if there are no documents in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

The most performant way to check if documents exist in a collection is to use the `EstimatedDocumentCount` function on a collection because it gets an estimate from the collection's metadata.

You can do something like this:

```golang
count, err := collection.EstimatedDocumentCount(context.Background())
```

If the actual count of documents in the collection is important and you need more than just an estimate, it makes sense to look into the MongoDB aggregation framework.

You can do something like this which wraps the aggregation framework:

```golang
count, err := collection.CountDocuments(ctx, bson.M{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if count >= 1 {
    fmt.Println("Documents exist in this collection!")
}
```

You could also try something like the following if you want to use the aggregation framework directly:

```golang
cursor, err := episodesCollection.Aggregate(ctx, []bson.D{
    bson.D{{"$count", "mycount"}},
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var counts []bson.M
cursor.All(ctx, &counts)
fmt.Println(counts[0]["mycount"])
```

Comment: Would passing "limit=1" as an option to CountDocuments() speed up the query?

Comment: I don’t think so, but you can try